# How to install Ktechlab in ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: installation, ide

I'm trying to install the ktechlab in ubuntu 13.04 but the .deb has some dependecies errors and it is not available in the software center.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Browser: Go to http://apt-web.dahsy.at/ and search for *ktechlab*. Download all links.
2. In terminal :

   ```
   cd files_path ; example : cd Downloads
   ```
3. Install all from terminal with:

   ```
   dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

Note: You can use another apt-web website, if it's available in your country